# How to copy a directory from local drive to a shared network using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I am attempting to copy a directory and its subdirectories from my D drive to a shared network but I continue getting the error as

**Exception:**

> **Could not find a part of the path '/Projects/08.ASP.NETProjects/ProjectName/'.**

My C# copy code:

```
 System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(D drive path);
 var destinationpath = "file:///BZ0025BZV43/Projects/08.ASP.NETProjects/ProjectName/";
 var uri = new Uri(destinationpath);
 var destinationurl = uri.AbsolutePath;
 foreach (System.IO.FileInfo mydirectory in directory.GetFiles())
 mydirectory .CopyTo(destinationurl);
```

I am new to FileHandlers. Please help.

Comment: So what does destinationUrl get set to?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `uri.LocalPath` instead of `uri.AbsolutePath`.

Also, be aware that you are trying to copy a file into a directory. But you have to copy the file into another file of that directory. (Directories are files too, basically).

So to do that check if the target directory exists and create it when necessary. Then replace `.copyTo(destinationUrl)` with `.copyTo(Path.Combine(uri.LocalPath, mydirectory.Name))` and you should be good to go. And please rename the variable `mydirectory` to `file` or something similar.

Also note that you are not copying the directory tree recursively. So if you want to recurse the tree, you have to check for subdirectories and copy the files in that hierarchy, too.

You can also check out this example: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb762914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)